# Convergence in probability only depends on topology?

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology

Suppose $(S,d)$ is a Polish space, and $X$, $(X_n)$ are random variables such that $X_n \to X$ in probability in $(S,d)$.  Now suppose $d'$ is another metric on $S$, giving the same topology.  Does $X_n \to X$ in probability in $(S,d')$?

I believe the answer is yes, and the following is a sketch proof.  Since $S$ is Polish, each of the laws of $X$, $X_n$ is tight (or "Radon") so for each $n$ there is a compact $K \subset S$ such that both $X$ and $X_n$ are in $K$ with high probability.  The metrics $d$ and $d'$ must be uniformly equivalent on $K$ (since they are continuous with respect to each other), and so making $X$ and $X_n$ close under $d$ is the same as making them close under $d'$.  By the convergence in probability hypothesis, we can do this.

If my reasoning is right, this must be something very standard.  Can someone confirm the result for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A sequence converges in probability to, say, $f$ iff every subsequence has a further subsequence that converges almost surely to $f$.  This second condition is independent of the metric that gives the topology, hence so is the first.

Comment: Indeed, that could be a good place to point out that a.s convergence is not topological (i.e. there is no topology on RV yielding it). This is because for any topological convergence we have that $x_n \to x$ if and only if any subsequence has a subsubsequence converging to $x$ (which is not the case for a.s. convergence).

Comment: Yes, Ori, and that convergence in probability is what you get when you try to turn convergence almost surely into a topological mode of convergence. Real variables 101.

Comment: I'm not sure about "Real variables 101", but I am pretty sure I've never been taught this, and it came as a great surprise to me when I found it out just a few years ago. Are you aware of other common notions of convergence which are not topological?

Comment: I don't know of any other common ones, Ori.